# Parallax effect of the apple site, macOS Monterey

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, parallax

I saw the "Design" page of Apple's presentation of macOS Monterey. They used a "parallax effect". When I inquired on the internet, they told me that there are many JavaScript libraries that animate the elements according to what I need when the page is scrolled, but what exactly did Apple use?
Here's the link [macOS Monterey](https://www.apple.com/it/macos/monterey-preview/)

Comment: I don't believe that page is using a parallax effect. I believe you're referring to the animations used at the top of the page? Apple is using custom code for all of that.